# Convert series of images to RTSP

Tags: ffmpeg, gstreamer, rtsp

I have a project where I receive RTSP stream from the camera, process each frame and then add metadata to each frame such as bounding boxes and texts. Now I need to convert this image back to RTSP? On the internet, I could find many libraries/utilities to restream to RTSP, but nothing to generate RTSP from series of images.

In short, I am looking to have a solution on how I can convert series of images to RTSP

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can use gstreamer rtsp server for example with [python](https://github.com/davidvuong/gstreamer-test/blob/master/src/python/opencv-rtsp-server.py).
and opencv, I think thats a good starting point.